# What's the recommended way to prefix Console.Write?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I'm looking for a way to insert a prefix (date and time) to every Console.Write[Line]. I'm looking for a recommended way to do so, just like the recommended way for changing the output is to use [Console.SetOut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setout.aspx).

I'm well aware that I can do String.Format("{0} {1}", DateTime.Now, msg), but I'm trying to leave that as my last resort.

The problem is that the output is changeable at run time, and the default one already appends the current time. If I append it on my code I will duplicate the date.

Is there such a thing? I'm using Monotouch, so I can only use libraries compiled for it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to [inherit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.aspx) from `System.IO.TextWrite`, provide an `Encoding` and overrides for e.g. `WriteLine` and `Write`. Store the original `Console.Out` before changing with `Console.setOut(x)`.

Here's a complete code example:

```
class PrefixedWriter : TextWriter
{
    private TextWriter originalOut;

    public PrefixedWriter()
    {
        originalOut = Console.Out;
    }

    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
        get { return new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding(); }
    }
    public override void WriteLine(string message)
    {
        originalOut.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} {1}", DateTime.Now, message));
    }
    public override void Write(string message)
    {
        originalOut.Write(String.Format("{0} {1}", DateTime.Now, message));
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.SetOut(new PrefixedWriter());
        Console.WriteLine("test 1 2 3");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the best way. MonoTouch 5.3+ redirect the `Console.Write*` to `NSLog` to work around the **stdout** limitation Apple added in iOS 5.1. The preliminary version of the source code is available on my blog: http://spouliot.wordpress.com/2012/03/13/ios-5-1-vs-stdout/

Comment: Love how it nicely integrates and solves the problem with double dates mentioned in the question

Answer (score 8):

You could just replace the Console call with your own class.

```
class MyConsole
{
   public static void WriteLine(string msg)
   {
      Console.Write(String.Format("{0} {1}", DateTime.Now, msg));
   }
}
```

Then of course, all calls to `Console.Write` become `MyConsole.Write`.

You could also take it a step further and alias `Console` with `MyConsole` in all code files...

```
using Console = MyNamespace.MyConsole;
```

Comment: This is exactly what i'm doing right now. Was wondering if there was a way to plug in to the current architecture

Comment: Although, this solution works, it doesn't deal with the double date when using the original console output.